# Windows 10 New-Netnat got windows system error 31

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v

I was following this link to set up NAT for Hyper-v VM except that I used GUI to create the virtual switch instead of using powershell.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network

When I tried to create a NAT using new-netnat in powershell, I got this:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> new-netnat -name NAT -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24
new-netnat : A device attached to the system is not functioning.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-netnat -name NAT -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_NetNat:root/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetNat) [New-NetNat], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 31,New-NetNat

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huMiO.png)

Yes I ran powershell as Administrator.
Get-netnat shows nothing.

I'm running Windows 10 [Version 10.0.10240].

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The NAT feature was introduced in Windows 10 build 10586. You must update your OS to a build greater than 10586 (currently 16299 for version 1709).

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_1709_(Fall_Creators_Update)_2) for version history.